# Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-services

We installed angular firebase with

```
npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
```

And this error occured

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(10,22): error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'FirebaseApp'.
Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.
```

How can I solved it?

Answer (score 12):

I would **advise against** modifying your `node_modules` directly. It is unnecessary and bad practise, as your changes will be overwritten by updates.

Op's error seems to occur when using a combination of the latest `firebase@4.13.1` and `angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6`.

**Solution:**

Some suggest downgrading the `firebase` package, but a better option might be installing `@firebase/app@^0.1.10` which fixed the errors in my case.

**Note:**

The latest firebase `4.13.1` introduces some changes to Firestore Timestamp/Date objects, that I had already implemented, and would have to revert if downgrading the `firebase` package.

Comment: You are right! installing "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7.0-next", compiled successfully. Thanks!

Comment: I had to install `angularfire2@next` (5.0.0-rc.7.0-next), didn't work.  Then installed `@firebase/app@^0.1.10` and it worked!  Funny that mine stopped working right after changing styles to sass with `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` and renaming the files, wonder if that changed some package versions?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Stopped working how? I'm using Firebase Auth with the above configuration.

Answer (score 11):

This work for me. Edit firebase.app.module.d.ts file

```
export declare class FirebaseApp implements FBApp {
name: string;
options: {};
automaticDataCollectionEnabled: boolean; // this is the missing line
auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
database: () => FirebaseDatabase;
messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
storage: () => FirebaseStorage;
delete: () => Promise<any>;
firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
}
```

also add @firebase/app

```
npm i -S @firebase/app
```

**EDIT**

The problem is solved by installing `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7"`

Just run `npm install angularfire2@latest`

Comment: Now it showing "ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/src/app/app.module.ts"

Comment: @Midhilaj which version of angularfire2 did you have? I'm working with 5.0.0-rc.6.0.

Comment: "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",

Comment: Did you install @firebase/app?

Comment: we was trying to install firebase in this template https://md-pro-angular.creative-tim.com/?_ga=2.245022725.1629331786.1524645055-922085387.1524220246 from https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-pro-angular2 and we tried many times and we quit this attempt. We started to create our own admin template using mdl . and if you find a solution to use firebase with above admin free template in angular 2 , please inform me

Comment: And it is working when we start from zero, but it is not working when we try to install firebase in angular2 admin template provide buy others

Comment: @Midhilaj MDL is deprecated, use MDC (Material Design Components) instead.

Comment: <b>Problem Solved</b>
<br> npm uninstall angularfire2 firebase --save
<br> npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
<br> npm install firebase --save

Answer (score 5):

Try to use these dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
 "firebase":"4.12.1",
 "angularfire2":"^5.0.0-rc.6",
 "@firebase/app": "^0.1.10" 
}
```

Comment: this works for me. but if I use the latest ^0.2.0 for @firebase/app, it failed.

Comment: This worked for me, although I didn't change @firebase/app since I'm not using that, just firebase and angularfire2. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I upgraded firebase to `4.13.1`

To fix that I updated angularfire2 to `^5.0.0-rc.7.0-next`

And my dependencies look's like:

```
"dependencies":{
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7.0-next",
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
}
```

Comment: This has worked for me, even without adding a `@firebase/app` as a direct dependency.
There might be a warning about a future deprecation of dates (if you are using `updated_at` or `created_at`), but it is easy to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change
node_modules\angularfire2\firebase.app.module.d.ts

> Before

```
export declare class FirebaseApp implements FBApp {
    name: string;
    options: {};
    auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
    database: () => FirebaseDatabase;
    messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
    storage: () => FirebaseStorage;
    delete: () => Promise<any>;
    firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
}
```

> After

```
export declare class FirebaseApp implements FBApp {
    name: string;
    automaticDataCollectionEnabled: boolean;
    options: {};
    auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
    database: () => FirebaseDatabase;
    messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
    storage: () => FirebaseStorage;
    delete: () => Promise<any>;
    firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
}
```

it should solve this issue until angularfire will come up with solution :)

**Edit**

Angularfire2 should come with a solution tmrw so I would consider to set a timer to update the library tomorrow :)
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1576

Comment: Now it showing "ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/lampp/htdocs/admin/src/app/app.module.ts"

Answer (score 0):

Try and rollback through the cli

```
npm install @firebase/app@0.1.10
```

Comment: now it showing <br>WARNING in ./~/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.js
3:40-54 "export 'InjectionToken' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angularfire2/angularfire2.js
4:26-40 "export 'InjectionToken' was not found in '@angular/core'

ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module

Comment: I recommend cleaning up, that will get rid of mismatches. npm cache clean and start from scratch

Comment: <b>Problem Solved</b>
<br> npm uninstall angularfire2 firebase --save
<br> npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
<br> npm install firebase --save

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with AngularFire 5.0.0-rc.3 is incompatible with any version of firebase greater than 4.6.0

so add these in package.json

```
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3", "firebase": "4.6.0",
```

and run `npm install`

Comment: <b>Problem Solved</b>
<br> npm uninstall angularfire2 firebase --save
<br> npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
<br> npm install firebase --save

Comment: Good luck then.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i get the same error:

ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(10,22): error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'FirebaseApp'.
  Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.

The solution is implements the FBapp into "firebase.app.module/ts". For this  add the code below:

```
"automaticDataCollectionEnabled: boolean;"
```

inside the firebase.app file into section FBApp